# Is there a closed form solution to this summation?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to calculate the expectation of a random variable and I've ended up with the following summation that I need to evaluate. I've tried a number of things including summation by parts, etc, but I can't find a way of solving it. Is there a closed form solution?

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom nk\frac {p^k (1-p)^{n-k}}{a+k}
$$

Here, $a>0$ is an arbitrary integer parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: it leads to a hypergeometric function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How would I go about determining the parameters of the hypergeometric function that represents it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dot product between a row vector the elements of which are the probability of some events and a column vector the elements of which are 1/(a+k).